# Does the Drakewarden's Drake have to increase in size at lv7 and lv15?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, archetype

So, I'm playing a Drakewarden Ranger and at lv7, the drake grows in size.
The rules state the following:

> In addition, while your drake is summoned, you and the drake gain the following benefits:
> **Drake Mount.** The drake grows to Medium size. Reflecting your special bond, you can use the drake as a mount if your size is Medium or smaller. While you are riding your drake, it can’t use the flying speed of this feature.

And at lv15:

> **Large Drake.** The drake grows to Large size. When you ride your drake, it is no longer prohibited from using the flying speed of Bond of Fang and Scale.

I don't want to use the drake as a mount and would rather have a small drake by my side than a large, bulky drake. So my question is: **Does the drake HAVE to become medium (or large at lv15)?**

In my mind, there would be three solutions:

- Simplest: He just grows, deal with it.
- Simple: Drake stays small and you don't get the benefit of Drake Mount and Large Drake at all.
- Greedy: Stays small, still gets flying speed.

Just to clarify why I ask for RAW or opinions is the following:

- If the drake stays small, it can position more easily against large foes and doesn't really provide cover for enemies when others use ranged attacks.
- If it grows, it eventually takes up melee space, provides cover for enemies and blocks my party and in general makes the drake less viable in dungeons (unless they have huge rooms/passageways).

That's about it. Any answers, be it opinions or RAW, are welcomed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 19):

#### The rules say it does

You quoted the rules correctly.  At 7th level, the drake grows to Medium, and at 15th it grows to Large.

#### Work it out with your DM

What matters is **your game**.  You can discuss with your DM whether they'll allow you to alter how the subclass works in your case.  It's probably a pretty reasonable ask, but only your DM can give an answer for your game.

Of course, you'll lose the not-insignificant benefit of a mount, and eventually a flying mount.

It's probably reasonable that the drake keeps its flying speed, but again, only your DM can answer.